# Compare lists in VBA and output differences in Msgbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have two lists with data. 
The first list is a list with all the new data and in the second list I have the old data. Now I want Excel to dislay a message box where it tells me which data are missing in the second list.

Using info found in other topics, I have been able to compare these two lists to each other and output this data in a third sheet. 
However I don't really need a third sheet, but I want to have these differences in a message box.. :) Can anyone help me out how I can change this code properly?

```
Sub Compare()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, c As Range
Set sh1 = Sheets(1)
Set sh2 = Sheets(2)
Set sh3 = Sheets(3)
lr1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = sh1.Range("A2:A" & lr1)
Set rng2 = sh2.Range("A2:A" & lr2)

With sh3 'If header not there, put them in
    If .Range("a1") = "" Then
       .Range("a1") = "Extras in List 2"
    End If
End With

    For Each c In rng2
        If Application.CountIf(rng1, c.Value) = 0 Then
        sh3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2) = c.Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non tested - entered directly in SO, but should show the way: (start after `End With`)

```
dim msg as string
msg  = "Extras: "

For Each c In rng2
    'edit: skip empty cells
    If len(c.Value) > 0 And Application.CountIf(rng1, c.Value) = 0 Then
        'sh3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(2) = c.Value
        msg = msg & c.value & ", "
    End If
Next
msg = left(msg,len(msg)-2)
msgbox msg
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Patrick! It almost works, however it now shows the message:

"Extra's: , , , , 6 , 8"

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I found where my prior issue was, I had some blank rows as well, which were identified as "new" as well. However blank rows need to be ignored by the code

Comment: I get a sintax error with this new code. It relates to row "   If if len(c).Value > 0 And Application.CountIf(rng1, c.Value) = 0 Then".. Any idea?

Comment: double `if` -- was easy to spot -- and `len(c.Value)`

Comment: It now works perfectly! thanks a lot! I have though one last question, if no differences occur can you program the code so that nothing happens? (so no message)

Comment: @ErikSlui: can't YOU do it ? Just check the lenght of the final msg, if it's different from the original, then display the msgbox.

Answer (score 0):

@PatrickHonorez has the better answer because he corrects the OP's code.

Whenever comparing two lists, I use some sort of Collection or Dictionary.

My approach was to add all the values from the 2nd list to an ArrayList and then remove the 1st list values from the ArrayList.  In this way only the new values are left in the ArrayList.

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim cell As Range, list As Object
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    With Worksheets(2)
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                If Not list.Contains(cell.Value) Then list.Add cell.Value
            End If
        Next
    End With

    With Worksheets(1)
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If list.Contains(cell.Value) Then list.Remove cell.Value
        Next
    End With

    With Worksheets(3)
        .Columns(1).ClearContents
        .Range("A1") = "Extras in List 2"

        If list.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No new data", vbInformation, ""
        Else
            MsgBox Join(list.ToArray, ", "), vbInformation, "New Data"
            .Range("A2").Resize(list.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(list.ToArray)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. If I had to do something like that from scratch, I would probably use an ADO query with a left join. https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/278973/excelado-demonstrates-how-to-use-ado-to-read-and-write-data-in-excel-w

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Thomas, this also seems to work, however this one also includes blank cells in its "differneces" list

Comment: Any idea how to exclude these?